# Routing search engine friendly URLs for Search in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have made a tool for checking seo stats like PR, DA, etc. There's one issue which I am trying to solve but couldn't. When a user enters a website in the search bar.

The url of the page comes as

```
http://seopoints.org/websites/index?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com
http://seopoints.org/websites/index?url=domain.com
http://seopoints.org/websites/index?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com
http://seopoints.org/websites/index?url=www.domain.com
```

But I want the URL of the page to come like this.

```
http://seopoints.org/websites/domain.com
```

How should I do this? I am using CakePHP. Need help in writing code in routes file.

Website URL: http://seopoints.org/

Comment: This does not make it SEO friendly, the opposite more likely, as you make them **invalid** when you contain those specific chars unescaped outside the query string...

Comment: @mark but the url will be more user friendly.

Comment: Then you need to make sure none of those special chars are in there.

Comment: @mark how to do this?

Comment: By not using the protocol and scheme, so only "domain.com" ever. Which you did in your last example. and then use "passed params" to catch it in your routes and controller action.

Answer (score 0):

As mark say "http://seopoints.org/websites/domain.com" is not SEO friendly.

Did http://seopoints.org/websites?q=domain.com work??

Thanks..!